# QT drag and drop draws image back to start

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using drag and drop in my application and it works fine. Except that qt animates a move of the dropped object back to its starting point. Here is my code.

```
mDrag = new QDrag(this);
mDrag->setPixmap(scaledPixmap);
mDrag->setHotSpot(dragHotSpot);
mDrag->setMimeData((mimeData));
setAcceptDrops(true);
Qt::DropAction dropAction = mDrag->exec();
```

Probably related to this is the fact that qt never calls the widget's `dropEvent` function. Also the `dropAction` is always `Qt:IgnoreAction`.